# How to use conditional (ternary) operator with nested if statements?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I want to add more nested "if statements" in the succeeding lines but I don't know what to do while using ternary operator.

```js
Object.freeze (phoneBook)

function lookup(name, address) {
  
for (let i = 0; i < phoneBook.length; i++) 

{

return (phonebook[i].givenName === name)? phoneBook[i][address]: "Not in the phonebook";
    
}
```

Comment: Shouting _"PLEASE HELP"_ in the title won't help you at all.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: _"...while using ternary operator"_ - Just don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply my friend :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary operations are hard to read if they are in any way complex. It rapidly becomes very difficult to work out what level you are at if there is much nesting.

Therefore for maintainability, especially if others are likely to have to support your code in the future, if then else statements properly laid out with indentation are probably a better way to go, even if you find yourself having to repeat return statements more than you would like.

Keep ternary statements for truly simple, one line, situations.

Comment: Thank you A Haworth for an eye opening answer :D I'm only just 2 weeks as a beginner  in javascript I have no any background in coding. Your answer boost me to be better my friend!